routing packets with mac-address with LAA bit
I use libpcap to send-receive packets between A and B, pcap_sendpacket() function.
In two type of connections

(1) A--router--B


(2) A--B

I need that in case (1) the packets will NOT go throuh the router and do NOT reach anyone in the local network. I was told it might be possible if the mac address of a source has LAA bit set to 1.
In general, as wiki says, it means the mac should be in range of f.e. x2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx (or x6-, or xA-, or xE-).
So

connections are setup in promiscuous mode to be able to get all packets regardelss of dest mac by calling pcap_set_promisc(1)
on sender side I fill in the structure [ethernet.h] ether_header.ether_shost accordingly
At the same time ether_header.ether_dhost (destination) is set to any mac, like 0-0-0-0-0-0, and
I put the structure in the outgoing buffer,
push this buffer to network by calling pcap_sendpacket().

All packets that I send with such mac addresses still go through the router, and if send by A - they are received by B without any problem or delay.
So my questions are

Is this true, that the packet with source mac address with LAA bit should be dropped by the router/switch?
If not, should exist some other way to setup source (or dest, or combination of source/dest?) mac address(es) to make packet dropped by router?

Finally
A--B connection type have to work with my specific packets, and
A-router-B should drop that packets.
Thank you!

This might be off-topic, more like superuser or networking stuff. Actually that's U/L bit. Setting up this part involves configuring routers, not endpoints

It should be. But I saw implementations of hardare  that ignore that, or have on/off option to ignore. That can be industrial or military stuff, especially of our local make (me and you).


Unless you use multcast modern concentrators and routers shoudn't see packets not addressed to them. Again there are industrial stuff that can work as repeaters. Why you'e using promiscous mode? Sending LAA and multicast normally supporeted by OS


@Swift-FridayPie I need promiscuous mode at receiver side to detect that it is connected to some network or to a router - by catching any packet with mac-dest different from my specific one. Dlink dir-300 router lets the packets with LAA bit go through.

Could this happen, that the rule to flood the packets with unknown mac-dest has higher priority over the rule to drop packets with LAA in mac-source?

Oh dir-300? It quite possible they hit an edge case. It got bridge and AP modes along with DMZ, these ignore U/L afaik.
